# My other Windows 10 machine can't access the other one

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, home-networking

So file sharing is working well with my laptop. I have mapped some of it's folders to my desktop etc. But from laptop I can't access my desktop. I can see the machine but I get the "Windows cannot access X" error:

[image: Network Error]

Windows Network Diagnostics says that the resource is online but isn't responding to connection attempts:

[image: Windows Network Diagnostics]

I'm sure there's some switch or policy that can solve this instantly. Google really didn't help me :/

Comment: Windows Network Diagnostics says that the resource is online but isn't responding to connection attempts.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot or whatever. Please elaborate the `X` error. If it provide error code.

Comment: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/HjFItix.png) [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/Xe5xbdq.png) It's like this on both computers

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting closer. I shared a new folder with "Everyone" and this is what I'm getting [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/bGibZov.png) [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/ds3wNp2.png) I find this strange as it's my local computer. I tried to allow all incoming connections in Private Profile but no luck.

Comment: That second picture specifically references a `File and Printer sharing` error.  Did you complete the steps within the screen shots that I posted below?  Taking it a step further, did you ensure that the desktop's current configuration is using the `Private` network profile?  And once again, *"did you check for "third-party security software on the desktop that could potentially be blocking access?"*

Comment: Yes I did. File and printer sharing is on and has been on. I only have Malwarebytes installed but it's not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the answer. I didn't have SMB enabled in "Windows features". Now sharing works for both computers.

Comment: Glad to hear that you resolved the issue, and after the two-day waiting period you can flag your own answer as the official solution.  That being said, do you have any idea how your system would have disabled that feature?  It seems like something that a third-party security application would modify, and it was never reset back to default status afterwards.

Comment: It's little embarassing but I think I have disabled it by myself... My Windows installation is very old as I have upgraded from 7. So my defense is that it was like 5 years ago haha. I'm new to this site and I was just yeasterday looking for an option to mark this solved. So thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you ensured that there isn't any third-party security software on the desktop that could potentially be blocking access?

Second, does the desktop possess the same login account credentials that the laptop is currently trying to utilize to access the desktop resources remotely?

Last but not least, have you already configured the desktop for File and Printer sharing?

1. Hold the <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and open the `Control Panel` in icons view.
2. Click on the `Network and Sharing Center`
3. Click on `Change advanced sharing settings` on the upper-left.
   [image: Change advanced sharing settings]
4. Expand the section that says `Private (current profile)`
5. Select the radio button to `Turn on file and printer sharing`
   [image: Turn on file and printer sharing]
6. Select `Save changes` at the bottom and acknowledge the UAC prompt, if necessary.

([Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49753-file-printer-sharing-turn-off-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: Sadly that's not it. I can see all the shared folders but I can't open any of them.

Comment: Forgive me, but you still aren't giving us enough information to work with.  When you say *"that's not it,"* did you actually check for all three potential causes that I mentioned in my post?  Beyond that, which folders on the desktop can you see (and are trying to access)?  It is the Public folders, or are there other folders that you specifically shared from the desktop?

Comment: Sorry. This is how my desktop looks like on File Explorer: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/FFmp0v9.png) Those are folders that I have shared. I can't open any of them. I did check "Advanced sharing" [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/MNFisRt.png)

Comment: My apologies for sound repetitive, but it looks like your desire to maintain privacy is preventing you from answering questions that will allow us to help you.  I appreciate your efforts, but a picture of blank folders doesn't really help us.  As I said before, *"It is the Public folders, or are there other folders that you specifically shared from the desktop?"*  Also, did you check for *"third-party security software on the desktop that could potentially be blocking access?"*  And does the *"desktop possess the same login account credentials"* (userid/password) that the laptop is using?

Comment: No worries, I appreciate every effort!  With that picture I wanted to show that those folders have been shared. I checked and both have same user names. Also Guest accounts are enabled. Laptop is not saying that it can't connect to port 445

Answer (score -1):

If you can see the shared folders but get an "Access Denied" error when you try and open them then it sounds like a permissions problem. If Laptop I and the desktop aren't logging in with the exact same username and password they you will get this error.

Comment: You should provide detailed steps, on how to determine if it is a permission problem, how to fix the permission problem.  Saying you think it's a permission problem isn't really helpful if the author doesn't know how to fix the permission problem, and if they did, they likely wouldn't need to ask the question that was asked.